Draw rectangle/oval tool missing from Digitizing Toolbar in QGIS 3
My GIS workspace contains a tool called 'draw rectangle geometry' within Digitizing Toolbar. However my colleague who has the same exact version of QGIS (3.16.1) does not have that tool.
I have managed to track it down to the difference in the Settings - Interface Customization where I have the tool available under the mDigitazeToolBar in Toolbars section but my colleague does not. It's not that it is inactive, it's not there at all.
What could be the source of that? As far as I'm aware QGIS was installed the same way (using same install file even) but this is also the case for other colleagues with different version, only I have the tool.

These tool seem to come from the "Geometry Shapes" plugin (or a similar one), check in "Plugins>Manage and Install Plugins>Installed" to see witch plugins you have installed and if any of them could provide these tool

@J.R. you are a star! thank you! I must have added the plugin while still on old version 2.xx and it just carried forward.

Also, they are only available for Polygon layers.  If you have a linestring, you can use Digitize with Curve after selecting the "Add Linestring" button.

These tool seem to come from the "Geometry Shapes" plugin (or a similar one), check in "Plugins>Manage and Install Plugins>Installed" to see witch plugins you have installed and if any of them could provide these tool
As @CaryH commented :

they are only available for Polygon layers. If you have a linestring,
you can use Digitize with Curve after selecting the "Add Linestring"
button

